Can a torsion-free module get torsion when extended to the integral closure?
Let $A$ be an integral domain, which is finitely generated as a $\mathbb C$-algebra. Consider it's normalization
$$A \subset \tilde A.$$
In a discussion, the following came up: Take a torsion free, finitely generated $A$-module $M$. Can it happen that $\tilde M = M \otimes_A \tilde A$ has torsion?
An example or a proof of the converse would be appreciated.
Clearly if $M$ is projective, so is $\tilde M$, so in this case no.

Take $A = k[t^2,t^3]$, $\tilde{A} = k[t]$, and $M = (t^2,t^3) \subset A$.

What is the torsion element?  I'd think you have $M \simeq A^2 / \langle (t^3, -t^2) \rangle$, so $M \otimes_A \tilde A \simeq \tilde A^2 / \langle (t^3, -t^2) \rangle$ and a possible torsion element would be $(t, -1)$, corresponding to $t^2 \otimes t - t^3 \otimes 1 \in M \otimes_A \tilde A$?

I would use the fact that $A/M = k$, which implies that $$\mathrm{Tor}_1^A(k,\tilde{A}) \subset M \otimes_A \tilde{A}.$$ This is exactly the torsion submodule.

As a correction to my prevous comment, it looks like actually $M \simeq A^2 / \langle (t^3, -t^2), (t^4, -t^3) \rangle$.  That still ends up giving $M \otimes_A \tilde A \simeq \tilde A^2 / \langle (t^3, -t^2) \rangle$.

@Sasha How do you know that $\mathrm{Tor}_1^A(k,\tilde{A})\ne0$?

@user26857: consider the minimal free resolution for $\tilde{A}$ over $A$. By minimality after tensor product with $k$ all become zero. So, the only possibility for $\mathrm{Tor}_1$ to be zero is if $M$ is locally free, which is obviously not the case.

@Sasha One can also invoke the non-flatness of $\tilde A$ over $A$. Anyway, all these comments show how terse was your answer.

@DanielSchepler Looks good to me, I got the same result.
